# How to manually create podcast using File Explorer

Tags: audio, podcast

I have a bunch of MP3 files that I want to treat as a podcast, so I can pause and resume without losing my spot. How do you set up folder structures and other necessary files in Windows Phone 8.1 to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In oder to get podcasts into your podcast app you actually have to subscribe to one, either by searching our by entering a feed.
You still can listen to the mp3s though the music app.

It might be easier though to try one of the audio book apps from the store - I think those offer the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What is your end goal? Can Playlists suffice your scenario? Learn how to create a playlist from here - http://webcazine.com/4443/how-to-create-playlists-for-windows-phone-8-on-your-windows-pc/

Comment: i want to pause and resume without losing my spot in the mp3.   Simple music does not seem to support this so I hoped to create the required files on the Phone's file system.  So far my efforts have failed so I was hoping someone could show me how.

Comment: If you have a webserver, I believe you can create and publish your own podcast and then import it into the Podcast app like this - http://www.citeworld.com/article/2369155/mobile-byod/using-the-podcasts-app-on-windows-phone-8-1.html